# How to synchronize two mysql databases?

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I have 2 servers: one i our office,  running WAMP and it has company's database; second is remot with our webpage and client panel.

Firstly, i can't change it, as we have low bandwith in our office, so the database must run locally. Same reason website needs to be outside.

Now, we store in database info about clients, including payments, presences and such. Few months back i created panel, with gives access to this information to those clients, but for now i have to copy db manually from one server to the other.

What are safe methods to automate this? I read about replication, i have the tab in my server's phpmyadmin, but there isn't one on hosting's.

I was thinking about changing each db query on my database into function, which would also encrypt that query and run it on remote server. Would it be good idea?

Kindly,
Trawa ;)

Comment: If your database is designed to audit any changes it should be a simple case of sending a list of changes, it's how normal replication works(but normally replication works on a smaller scale with transaction logs)

Comment: I suggest to use the mysql integrated replication feature, maybe this guide can help you to set it up correctly: http://lasanthals.blogspot.ch/2012/09/mysql-replication-server-configuration.html

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36354/how-to-sync-mysql-database-between-two-servers